Linux, How to stop or fix vlc messages in bash?
VLC media player in GUI works fine on final.mp3
GUI = graphical user interface
Thus final.mp3 audio is playing ok.
But, vlc messages via a:
bash script or
CLI command line interface.
commands issued:
1
vlc /tmp/f/final.mp3
2
"/usr/bin/vlc" "/tmp/f/final.mp3"
3
vlc /home/x/Desktop/final.mp3
As audio is playing, message is:
[00006183c60df580] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.

After audio finishes, message is:
uint DBusMenuExporterDBus::GetLayout(int, int, const QStringList&, DBusMenuLayoutItem&): Condition failed: menu  
uint DBusMenuExporterDBus::GetLayout(int, int, const QStringList&, DBusMenuLayoutItem&): Condition failed: menu  
^[[A^CQObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread  

No desire to use 'cvlc', regarding message:
Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
final.mp3 plays fine in
GUI
bash
CLI
But in bash and CLI there are messages, see above.
And in bash and CLI a Ctrl-c is required to continue.  Undesired.
using
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
VLC version 3.0.16 Vetinari (3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
to display above:
neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'
vlc --version |head -n1
https://www.videolan.org/vlc/
--

Learn how to run a program in background and how to redirect the output for suppressing it. vlc /tmp/f/final.mp3 >/dev/null 2>&1 & will suppress all output and run the program in background. (I don't know if vlc` has command line options to suppress the output in the program itself.)

vlc  /tmp/f/final.mp3 >/dev/null 2>&1
does suppress the problem but
does not fix the problem.
The undesired part stays the same in that in bash ...
Ctrl-c is required to continue. Undesired.

Please note the additional & after the output redirection to run the program in background. (I did the formatting wrong in my previous comment.)

The closest thing to an answer that I can find on VLC's bug tracker is this:

It's this:
Breakpoint 3, 0x00007fffd9bc6800 in QObject::~QObject() ()
  from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
(gdb) bt
[#0](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/0)  0x00007fffd9bc6800 in >QObject::~QObject() ()
  from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
[#1](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/1)  0x00007fffd9f48289 in >?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
[#2](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/2)  0x00007ffff568be08 in >__run_exit_handlers (status=0, 
   listp=0x7ffff59f45f8 <__exit_funcs>, 
   run_list_atexit=run_list_atexit@entry=true) at exit.c:82
[#3](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/3)  0x00007ffff568be55 in >__GI_exit (status=<optimized out>) at exit.c:104
[#4](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/4)  0x00007ffff5676617 in >__libc_start_main (main=0x401b97 <main>, argc=1, 
   argv=0x7fffffffe1d8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, 
   rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe1c8) at libc-start.c:325
[#5](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/5)  0x00000000004018f9 in >_start ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread

AFAIK, Qt documentation requires that QApplication be instantiated on the exiting thread. This violation of Qt API requirements was also why VLC crashes at exit within QtDbus with some versions of Qt.
(Of course, this is a stupid requirements and doing anything non-trivial in static object is evil. But unless we add Qt to contribs and patch it in, that's a VLC bug.)
--Rémi Denis-Courmont, @Courmisch

That you only see those messages upon completion of playing the mp3 file -- "After audio finishes" -- tells me that what they observe there may be related to what you are seeing here.
Given:

that VLC is a QT application
that the VLC team asks its users to use cvlc for terminal applications
that the aforementioned bug is not tagged as fixed

I suspect that you won't get a solution to this particular edge case from the VLC team, and you'll need to find some other way of handling the undesired output. The comments on your post about redirecting STDERR can help there.
As for negating the need for Ctrl+C within a bash command or script... I'm unable to precisely replicate your particular failure mode, with the DBus error messages about the menu, but my VLC does simply pause after finishing playback, rather than closing:
$ vlc music.mp3
VLC media player 3.0.21 Vetinari (revision 3.0.21-0-gdd8bfdbabe8)


This necessitates either quitting via the interface, or a ^C command. However, investigating the detailed help options of VLC gives this useful nugget (I found the --longhelp --advanced flags from initially checking the vlc manpage a la man vlc):
$ vlc --longhelp --advanced | grep -i quit
VLC media player 3.0.21 Vetinari (revision 3.0.21-0-gdd8bfdbabe8)
  vlc://quit                     Special item to quit VLC
      --global-key-quit <string> Quit
      --key-quit <string>        Quit
$

And, when I run the following, VLC quits upon finishing playing the mp3:
$ vlc music.mp3 vlc://quit
VLC media player 3.0.21 Vetinari (revision 3.0.21-0-gdd8bfdbabe8)
[000055d8ffffd520] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[00007f6838003420] idummy demux: command `quit'
$ echo $?
0
$ 

Perhaps tacking on  vlc://quit to your vlc commands in the bash shell and scripts will be sufficient for getting around the "I have to ^C" roadblock.
Edit: VLC also has the -q option for quiet output, which may or may not suppress some of the undesired messages. E.g.,
$ vlc -q music.mp3 vlc://quit
VLC media player 3.0.21 Vetinari (revision 3.0.21-0-gdd8bfdbabe8)
$ 

and for getting rid of the version:
$ vlc -q music.mp3 vlc://quit 2>/dev/null
$ 

(there is also a --no-version flag to vlc, but it does not appear to work on my particular install; perhaps it will work for you rather than redirecting STDERR to /dev/null)

Preston answers the question with _
vlc -q /tmp/f/final.mp3 vlc://quit 2>/dev/null _
above works with a bash script and
above works with CLI command line interface.
Preston added 3 parts:
-q and
vlc://quit and
2>/dev/null well done.
